# Parsing and Convert Data type into Json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have variable that contain array inside, when i was tried to print it with javascript console.log(res) show like this:

```
res = [{sakti: "23"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}]
```

How i suppose to do, if i want to change the data type into like this:

```
res = [{name: "sakti", y: 23},{name: "Baim", y: 20},{name: "Jaka", y: 18}]
```

my current code:

```
this.categoryservice.getRole().subscribe((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
let res = [{sakti: "23"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}]

let op = res.map(e=>{
  let key = Object.keys(e)[0]
  return { name: key, y: +e[key] }
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: yeah thanks sir @Code Maniac, but how about convert string number with double quotes into integer without double quotes ?

Comment: You can do by parseInt or, implicit conversion. look at the `+` in `y` property value i added it for implicit conversion to number

Comment: @tonjel _"but how about convert string number with double quotes into integer without double quotes"_ How is that inquiry related to the original question?

Comment: Perfect sir @CodeManiac, thanks it so helpful. so it does need  +

Comment: @tonjel yes, but i will suggest you to read more about string to number conversion that will help in long run, consider marking answer as correct one if it helped and solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

**[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** is another way of mapping the object array into a new array of objects by using the second mapping argument. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) &  [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) can be used to construct the new object by taking the `[0]` position from the key array which will be the `name` and `[0]` from the value array which will be the `y` key.

```js
const res = [{sakti: "23"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}]
const arrayConv = Array.from(res, obj => { return {"name":Object.keys(obj)[0], "y":Object.values(obj)[0] } });
console.log(arrayConv);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new experimental `flatMap()` you can create a generic approach (in case one of your object have more than one `key:val` pair):

```js
const res = [{sakti: "23", foo: "33"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}];

let mapped = res.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({name: k, y: +v})));

console.log(mapped);
```

But, you can always use `reduce()` for this too:

```js
const res = [{sakti: "23", foo: "33"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}];

let mapped = res.reduce(
    (acc, o) => acc.concat(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({name: k, y: +v}))),
    []
);

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array.map`, `Object.entries` and destructuring assignment:

```js
const data = [{sakti: "23"}, {Baim: "20"}, {Jaka: "18"}];

const result = data.map(item => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];
  return { name: key, y: value };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for this

```
 var res = [{sakti: "23"},{Baim: "20"},{Jaka: "18"}]

 var result = res.map((i)=>{
        let obj = Object.entries(i);
        return {'name': obj[0][0], 'y': obj[0][1]};
    });
console.log(result);
```